# Jquery toggle text button with bootstrap icon inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im working with Boostrap 3 and Jquery and Im trying toggle the text inside a button with an boostrap icon span, but doesnt know how to do. This is what I tried: 
The html code:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-md'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(this).text(function(i, text){
  return text === "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Close" ? "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit" : "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Close"
})
```

So...How could be this works?
 
1) An example with the toggle text button but keeping the same icon. 
2) Another example with the toggle text button but toggle the icon class
Thanks.

Comment: Since you're putting raw HTML into the element, you need to use `.html` instead of `.text`.

Comment: Finally I put the "Edit" text into a <span> tag, so more easier to replace the content. But thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ***===***  you can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) because:

```
$(this).text() === "↵     Edit"
```

Like you can see there is an extra char (newline) and you cannot rely on this.

The snippet with the jQuery.html is:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).html(function(i, text){
    return (text.indexOf("Close") != -1) ? "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit" : "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Close"
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-md'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button>
```

Or, in JS you may write:

```
this.childNodes[2].textContent = (this.childNodes[2].textContent.indexOf("Close") != -1) ? 
      ' Edit' : ' Close';
```

The snippet:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  this.childNodes[2].textContent = (this.childNodes[2].textContent.indexOf("Close") != -1) ? ' Edit' : ' Close';
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-md'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary toggle-text" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span><span>Edit</span><span class="hidden">Close</span>...
```

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').hide();
$('.toggle-text').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').each(function() { $(this).toggle(); });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bcwhh8cp/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `html()` instead of `text()`

```
$(this).html(function(i, text){
  return text === "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Close" ? "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit" : "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Close"
})
```